# How do you find unknowns inside distribution functions in R?

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis, normal-distribution, stochastic

I need to find the mean in for example
0.02 <- pnorm(400, mean = x, sd = 4)

how do I find x? Is R capable of solving equations?

Comment: Hint: have a look at `?qnorm`

Comment: @user20650 I guess you need a known mean to apply `qnorm`

Comment: `qnorm(0.02, 400, 4, FALSE)`

Comment: @user20650 Thanks! Good to know the magic of `qnorm`

Answer (score 3):

You might need `erfinv` from `pracma` to get the mean value `mu`, e.g.,

```
p <- 0.02
x <- 400
sgm <- 4
mu <- x - sgm*sqrt(2)*pracma::erfinv(2*p-1)
```

such that

```
> mu
[1] 408.215

> pnorm(400,mu,sgm) # check the obtained value of mu
[1] 0.02
```

---

**A smarter approach is via `qnorm` (thanks to @user20650)**

```
mu <- qnorm(p,x,sgm,FALSE)
```